# Qual seria a melhor prática, dentro do padrão MVC, para fazer o tratamento dos dados?

Tags: mvc

Um exemplo (eu costumo usar o CakePHP, mas a pergunta seria para qualquer framework e linguagem): para salvar campos do tipo data no banco dedos eu tenho que transformar um campo do formato `dd/mm/yyyy` em `yyyy-mm-dd`. Para tal, eu utilizo uma simples função chamada `converteData(data)` que fica dentro do AppController (classe-mãe de todos os controles do CakePHP). Então, a conversão fica assim:

```
$this->request->data['Cliente']['vinculoDataInicio'] = $this->converteData($this->request->data['Cliente']['vinculoDataInicio']);
```

Eu costumo fazer isso dentro dos controles. Assim, os dados são passados no formato certo para o modelo, que ainda vai validá-los antes de salvá-los.

Minha dúvida é: isso é o ideal ou eu deveria simplesmente passar todos os dados para o modelo para que ele trate, valide e salve os dados?

Comment: A responsabilidade do controller é geralmente atender os pedidos (requests) dos usários, tratar um data me parace uma tarefa especifica de outra classe :P. Lembre-se classes não são repositórios de funções.

Comment: @rray então o correto seria passar tudo para o modelo? Eu coloquei essa função no AppController apenas para que ficasse disponível para todos os outros controles, já que seu uso é recorrente.

Comment: @Bacco da view? Discordo. A view tem utilidade para o usuário, e como esse sistema é feito para usuários brasileiros, ele deve seguir as convenções que são utilizadas aqui. Eu não posso obrigar alguém a usar o formato yyyy-mm-dd. Mesmo que eu quisesse, o cliente viria me cobrar isso.

Comment: Ainda não concordo. Não creio ser o ideal usar uma solução de front-end. Penso que isso seria um pouco mais difícil de ser implementado e menos consistente, já que o usuário poderia fazer alterações na página.

Comment: Eu faria no modelo mesmo. Lá você provavelmente vai validar o valor, seria só fazer um parse antes da validação.

Comment: Você esta fazendo certo, quem fica responsavel por tratar dados é justamente o controller, o seu model tem que ficar responsavel apenas pelo registro/leitura de dados externos.

Imagine que você não precise tratar dados no controller e que você passe tudo diretamente para o model.........para que serviria o controller? você poderia passar tudo diretamente para o model sem intermedios concorda?

Comment: Removi os comments pq tava pensando na saida dos dados genericamente. De qq forma vale o que eu quis dizer sobre não trabalhar com os dados em DD/MM/AAAA, mas sim converter o quanto antes (na camada adequada, claro). No caso, não sei como o cake trabalha, mas se fosse algo em ajax, por exemplo, talvez eu não mandasse em DD/MM/AAAA nem na transmissão, mas realmente isso depende da arquitetura especifica.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly Tem uma grande controvérsia sobre isso. Vai sempre depender do caso específico, e pode ser o caso de usar uma classe totalmente separada (na terminologia do Cake, uma classe *vendor*). Leitura interessante: http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/04/fat-model-skinny-controller-is-a-load-of-rubbish/

Comment: Pensando bem, eu acho que isso é uma tarefa relacionada ao model. Estamos falando de dados puros que serão salvos no banco de dados, e é o modelo quem deveria fazer isso.